# Find a specific value from an exploded array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello so I have exploded a row from my database, I want to find a specific value based on the exploded array.

My row example.

```
    Josh Johnson|Jenny Launcher|Easter Fonter|Eric Bennett
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    $rowexplode = $row['name'];

    $a = explode("|",$rowexplode);
    if(count($a)>1) {

    $explode_results = $rowexplode;

    $explode_array = str_replace("|",", ", $explode_results);

    echo $explode_array;

    }
    else {
         echo "";
    }
    ?>
```

This is what it shows

```
    Josh Johnson, Jenny Launcher, Easter Fonter, Eric Bennett
```

Now I would like it to grab one of those names and display it.
For example. Grab Easter Fonter from the list and echo something like "Easter Fonter was here".

I don't know if it's possible to specify a specific name out of the exploded array.

Comment: Loop the array and check if the value is equal to what you want, if it is then assign to a variable and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to know what you've created at each step of the way:

```
<?php

$rowexplode = $row['name']; // $rowexplode is now a string

$a = explode("|",$rowexplode);
// $a is an array with strings, such as:
// array('Josh Johnson, 'Jenny Launcher', 'Easter Fonter', 'Eric Bennett')

if(count($a)>1) {
  $explode_results = $rowexplode;
  // $explode_results is now just a copy of $rowexplode, still just a string

  $explode_array = str_replace("|",", ", $explode_results);
  // This says array, but it isn't.  It's just a string with the pipes replaced:
  // "Josh Johnson, Jenny Launcher, Easter Fonter, Eric Bennett"

  echo $explode_array;
  // Output that string
}
```

So, if you want the values, you could do:

```
foreach ($a as $name) {
  echo "$name was here\n"; // Echo each name one at a time
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to set it up how you explained it next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in_array function to check. Since you already have data in array $a

```
if(in_array("Easter Fonter", $a))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ["Josh Johnson", "Jenny Launcher", "Easter Fonter", "Eric Bennett"];

foreach($arr as $name) {
    if($name == "Easter Fonter") {
        echo $name + " was here";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful

```
    //your text here
    $rowexplode = 'Josh Johnson|Jenny Launcher|Easter Fonter|Eric Bennett';

    $a = explode("|",$rowexplode);

    if(count($a)>1) {

    //your search string

    $name = "Easter Fonter";

    //check here
    if(in_array($name,$a))
    {
        echo $name." was here.";
    }else{

        echo "Name Not Found".implode(', ', $a);
    }

    }
    else {
         echo "";
    }
?>
```